# Write the Output into same xml file in Talend ETL

Tags: etl, talend

I want to use xml file to store records that processed by Talend job.I have created the Output XML file and using tAdvancedFileOutputXML to generate the output.Structure of XML is -

```
`<node>
    <successrecords>
        <data attribute="[value]" />
    </successrecords>
   <failurerecords>
       <data attribute="[value]" />
   </failurerecords>
```

`

Success and failure records has to be put in one XML but only the first assigned tAdvancedFileOutputXML is generating and the other one is not appending.Please suggest me how to write into same file at both failure and success scenario.

Comment: can you share your job with the tAdvancedFileOutputXML configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tXMLMap prior to writing to your XML file, there is an option on the output settings of the tXMLMap : `"All in one"` which allows you to write all the output rows into the same file.

[image]